# How to set schema into spark.sql.function.from_csv?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-java

I use spark-3.4.1-hadoop3 on windows 11. And I try to generate the schema to pass into from_csv function parameter.
Belows are my codes.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_csv;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("FromCsvStructExample").getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load("/path/to/csv/file");

Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();

String schemaString = "name string, age int, job string";

Column schema = from_csv(col("csv"), col(schemaString), options);
Dataset<Row> parsed = df.select(schema.as("data"));
parsed.printSchema();
spark.close();
```

But the codes throw the following exceptions.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [INVALID_SCHEMA.NON_STRING_LITERAL] The input schema "name string, age int, job string" is not a valid schema string. The input expression must be string literal and not null.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.unexpectedSchemaTypeError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:1055)    
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprUtils$.evalTypeExpr(ExprUtils.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprUtils$.evalSchemaExpr(ExprUtils.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CsvToStructs.<init>(csvExpressions.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.from_csv(functions.scala:4955)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_csv(functions.scala)
        at com.aaa.etl.processor.Test_CSV.main(Test_CSV.java:43)
```

I am afraid the schemaString is not correct for `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col` function. Kindly inform me how to generate the schema with `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col` function. I know there is overloaded from_csv function which schema parameter type is StructType. But in using this function I have to make scala function and I even have no basic knowledge of scala.

**== Updated Part**

I try to use the Java-specific from_csv method.

```
from_csv(Column e, Column schema, java.util.Map<String,String> options)
```

As you know the type of schema is not StructType, but Column. I am stuck on this part. I have no idea how to generate the Column type schema in java.
If you have any reference which generate the java Column type schema, Kindly inform me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right you can't generate directly a `Column` given a DDL string. One way is to use [lit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50b36d131326d1dc2503f20a35891e7f1b4b0194/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L117) or [StructType.fromDDL](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a84e2b1eee3bb868f140bffeba4e19b1a56fa3fb/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L523C7-L523C14) function. As you already mentioned one signature of [from_csv](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a84e2b1eee3bb868f140bffeba4e19b1a56fa3fb/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L7213) function accepts a StructType for the schema. Then the Scala code would look as next:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

var schema: StructType = StructType.fromDDL("name string, age int, job string")

// StructType(
//   StructField(name,StringType,true),
//   StructField(age,IntegerType,true),
//   StructField(job,StringType,true)
// )

val targetCol = from_csv(col("csv"), schema, options)
```

The code should be very similar for Java.

As per the other signature of [from_csv](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a84e2b1eee3bb868f140bffeba4e19b1a56fa3fb/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L7236), which accepts a [Column](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala) instead of a `StructType`, it is used in combination with `lit` function as shown in the corresponding unit [test](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50b36d131326d1dc2503f20a35891e7f1b4b0194/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/CsvFunctionsSuite.scala#L37). This is for cases where you prefer passing the schema as a string.

For your case that would have been:

```scala
val schema = "name string, age int, job string"

val targetCol = from_csv(col("csv"), lit(schema), options)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @abiratsis. I have another question and kindly check my updated part.

Comment: Normally, if your original question is answered, you should mark it as answered and not add another sub-question, but open another question for that.

Comment: @JosephHwang please check my updated answer I added some additional details for the version of from_csv which accepts a Column as the schema